How do I get the text for each tabs and the index of the selected Tab from the BasicTabbedPaneUI paintTab() method?
So a bit of background, I am creating a child class that extends the JTabbedPane() component, adding some extra methods and primarily have a specific appearance applied using the BasicTabbedPaneUI. In order to customize the tabs I have been overriding the paintTab() method but I am unable to see a way that I can get the index of the selected tab (in order to draw the selected tab differently), I also haven't been able to figure out quite how to get the text for each tab.
So far I have attempted to use the paintTabBackground() method (using the same code as I have used in the paintTab() method), but I don't believe it is the method to achieve what I am looking for, I have looked through the java docs and can't really see any indicators as to any other methods I should be using.
The current (relevant) code for myTabbedPaneUI (my implementation of BasicTabbedPaneUI is as follows:
private static class myTabbedPaneUI extends BasicTabbedPaneUI { 
    @Override
    protected void paintTab(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, Rectangle[] rects, int tabIndex, Rectangle iconRect, Rectangle textRect) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.PINK);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(rects[tabIndex].x, rects[tabIndex].y, rects[tabIndex].width, rects[tabIndex].height+20, 6, 6);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.drawRoundRect(rects[tabIndex].x, rects[tabIndex].y, rects[tabIndex].width, rects[tabIndex].height+20, 6, 6);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawString("Test String", 0, 0);
    }

I am more or less looking for a way to do something like so:
@Override
    protected void paintTab(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, Rectangle[] rects, int tabIndex, Rectangle iconRect, Rectangle textRect) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        if (tabIndex == selectedTabIndex){
            drawSelected();
        } else {
            drawUnselected();
        }

        g2d.drawString(tabText, 0, 0);

    }

Any help is appreciated, thanks all in advanced!

BasicTabbedPaneUI contains protected field tabPane. So from paintTab we can access int selectedTabIndex = tabPane.getSelectedIndex();  and String tabText = tabPane.getTitleAt(tabIndex);

@SharadPaul worked a charm! Thank you very much.
